# Loki takes long time to shut down

Tags: release-loki, shutdown

I recently installed Loki (64bit) in another of my laptops (I have Freya in the first one). Loki (as it is in Freya) boots very fast. My problem is in the shut down process. It takes awful long (compared to Freya). Will appreciate any help to troubleshoot this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by the Thermal Daemon Service not shutting down properly. The default timeout is 90s.

This can be resolved by changing the timeout length.

Run this command

```
sudo io.elementary.code /etc/systemd/system.conf
```

Delete the # in front of the the two lines below and change the 90s to something lower. I've set mine to 6s and my system shuts down very quickly.

```
DefaultTimeoutStartSec=90s
DefaultTimeoutStopSec=90s
```

Comment: I've opened an issue on this a while ago: https://github.com/elementary/default-settings/issues/10

Comment: When did you install your system. I just did a fresh install and noticed I haven't been experiencing this issue. A number of other issues I used to experience are no longer issues as well. So maybe some things have been fixed recently.

Comment: I personally haven't experienced the problem, but it probably depends on installed applications. I mostly thought it would be smart to lower that timeout to prevent applications to cause this issue in general. (why did I open that issue? I didn't like the fact that using an os involves using a workaround list)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem too! What I've seen is that if you turn on the computer and only a few minutes then you turn down the computer it won't last so much this also happens when you open few programs, but when working a lot on the OS it will take a long time for shooting. Hope this can be helpful and that it ain't something you already know