# Elementary OS does not shutdown correctly

Tags: release-loki, shutdown

When I shutdown via terminal or by clicking the button, it just shows a hyphen on the top left corner is stuck there forever. I manually have to interrupt with the key and shut it down.

Using Dell XPS 15 9560

Comment: same laptop same problem here. I am using dell xps 9560. after i install ubuntu-drivers-common, i can shutdown laptop properly but i found another issue that if you switch to Intel gpu i get boot error: timed out forcewake...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loki takes long time to shut down](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/11202/loki-takes-long-time-to-shut-down)

Comment: @vivek-patani, could you try the solution indicated in the answer Peter Uithoven linked to and let us know if that applies to your problem? Otherwise, this question would need more details to troubleshoot the actual issue, in which case a bug report would probably be a better place to carry on that process.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same laptop
the problem is with Nvidia driver.

you need to install "additional drivers"

```
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install ubuntu-drivers-common
```

**Or you can open AppCenter and install "additional drivers" from there.**

***I'm not sure that the package is called exactly that but you can look it up for the exact name***

after everything is installed
open additional drivers app and select Nvidia 381 driver

that should fix your issues

Comment: So figure out / verify the right nvidea driver, you can use the NVIDIA Driver Downloads page: http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx

Comment: ha? i've already figured it out

Comment: I was just trying to add more information, for people who might have slightly other hardware. And I remember how confusing those driver numbers where to me.  
(The "So" was a typo, should have been "To")

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/11202/loki-takes-long-time-to-shut-down). It could be a service is getting hung and can't shutdown properly. This fix adjusts the timeout for hung services.